# Terraform import of lambda-source-mapping

Tags: terraform

I have some unexpected changes in my terraform plan. When I run my plan I see it's trying to create a resource that already exists.

```
+ module.transactions-lambda.aws_lambda_event_source_mapping.lambda-source-mapping
    id:                        "<computed>"
    batch_size:                "1000"
    enabled:                   "true"
    event_source_arn:          "arn:aws:kinesis:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxx:stream/transactions"
    function_arn:              "<computed>"
    function_name:             "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxx:function:transactions"
    last_modified:             "<computed>"
    last_processing_result:    "<computed>"
    starting_position:         "LATEST"
    state:                     "<computed>"
    state_transition_reason:   "<computed>"
    uuid:                      "<computed>"
```

I then import that resource.

```
terraform import module.transactions-lambda.aws_lambda_event_source_mapping.lambda-source-mapping 6f9d38a9-3173-47e8-8951-380353959d33
```

I expect my plan now to display no changes. However, I see it's trying to force a new resource because:

- computing the "id"
- "Starting position" wants to be changed to
  latest.

```
-/+ module.transactions-lambda.aws_lambda_event_source_mapping.lambda-source-mapping (new resource required)
    id:                                   "6f9d38a9-3173-47e8-8951-380353959d33" => "<computed>" (forces new resource)
    function_arn:                         "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxx:function:transactions" => "<computed>"
    last_modified:                        "" => "<computed>"
    last_processing_result:               "OK" => "<computed>"
    maximum_batching_window_in_seconds:   "30" => "0"
    starting_position:                    "" => "LATEST" (forces new resource)
    state:                                "Enabled" => "<computed>"
    state_transition_reason:              "User action" => "<computed>"
    uuid:                                 "6f9d38a9-3173-47e8-8951-380353959d33" => "<computed>"
```

This is the truncated form of the module being called...

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {
  s3_bucket     = "${var.lambda_s3_bucket}"
  s3_key        = "${var.lambda_s3_key}"
  handler       = "${var.lambda_handler}"
  function_name = "${var.name}"
  runtime       = "${var.lambda_runtime}"
  timeout       = "${var.lambda_timeout_sec}"
  memory_size   = "${var.lambda_memory_size_mb}"
  role          = "${aws_iam_role.lambda-role.arn}"

  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids = ["${var.subnet_ids}"]

    security_group_ids = [
      "${aws_security_group.lambda-security-group.id}",
    ]
  }

  environment {
    variables = "${var.lambda_environment_variables}"
  }

  depends_on = ["aws_iam_policy.lambda-policy"]
}

...

resource "aws_lambda_event_source_mapping" "lambda-source-mapping" {
  batch_size        = "${var.lambda_batch_size}"
  event_source_arn  = "${var.kinesis_stream_arn}"
  enabled           = "${var.source_mapping_enabled}"
  function_name     = "${aws_lambda_function.lambda.arn}"
  starting_position = "${var.kinesis_starting_position}"
}

...
```

This is the terraform state list before doing the import. You can see here that the resource does not exist.

```
module.validation-lambda.aws_lambda_event_source_mapping.lambda-source-mapping
module.send-lambda.aws_lambda_event_source_mapping.lambda-source-mapping
module.status-lambda.aws_lambda_event_source_mapping.lambda-source-mapping
```

This is the terraform state list of the uuid in the import

```
[I] ➜ okta:sbux-prod $ aws lambda get-event-source-mapping --uuid 6f9d38a9-3173-47e8-8951-380353959d33
{
    "MaximumBatchingWindowInSeconds": 30,
    "UUID": "6f9d38a9-3173-47e8-8951-380353959d33",
    "StateTransitionReason": "User action",
    "LastModified": 1576562640.0,
    "BatchSize": 1000,
    "EventSourceArn": "arn:aws:kinesis:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxx:stream/transaction",
    "FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxx:function:transactions",
    "State": "Enabled",
    "LastProcessingResult": "OK"
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your Terraform code as an [mcve]? Ideally at least include the resource definition for the `aws_lambda_event_source_mapping.lambda-source-mapping` resource.

Comment: Also what does the output of `aws lambda get-event-source-mapping --uuid 6f9d38a9-3173-47e8-8951-380353959d33` show?

Comment: Added, Thanks @ydaetskcoR

Comment: Hmmm... the AWS API doesn't actually return the starting position when calling the `GetEventSourceMapping` endpoint so when you import it it can only set what it can get back from the API. Unfortunately it's also not something that can be updated so Terraform reads in a nil value from the read as part of the import and then sees it needs to update the `starting_position` and without there being an upgrade path then it has to destroy it and recreate it. I honestly can't see a good fix for this either as a user or as an occasional contributor.

Comment: This is a one off thing so you can either allow Terraform to recreate the event source mapping with the apply (I've not used Lambda event source mappings so not sure how bad that would be) or you could manually hack the state file to add the parameter until the diff goes away. Not good options I'm afraid :(

Comment: Looking at the [source code of the module](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/master/aws/resource_aws_lambda_event_source_mapping.go),  [ydaetskcoR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2291321/ydaetskcor) is right - the module itself needs fixing because the field won't allow you to explicitly set an empty string. The only other alternative to recreating the resource with Terraform is to ignore this field using [`ignore_changes`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#ignore_changes)

Comment: Unless I suppose you'd consider editing the state file by hand and adding the "missing" field?